# How to convert Carbon output in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

if I use `time()` the output is integer value like `"1458352898"`
and if i user carbon the output is date type... like here :

```
$timecarbon = Carbon\Carbon::now("Asia/Hong_Kong");

echo $timestring    //  2016-03-19 09:08:16

$timephp = time("Asia/Hong_Kong")

echo $timephp    //  1458352898
```

how to use `carbon::now`, but the output is like `time()`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try:

```
$now = Carbon\Carbon::now("Asia/Hong_Kong");

echo $now->timestamp;
```

Comment: @Megandi for your second question check here https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/636